# É um design usual que a operação de adição na unidade aritmética e lógica ocorra por padrão durante a execução de outras instruções?

Tags: assembly, soma, arquitetura-computadores, sistemas-digitais

O livro *But How Do It Know?* apresenta uma arquitetura de computador de 8 bits em que as instruções lógico-aritméticas (isto é, executadas pela unidade aritmética e lógica) possuem bit mais significativo 1, e são definidas pelos três bits seguintes, enquanto que as demais têm bit mais significativo 0.

Em particular, a instrução de adição tem op code binário 1000, e a arquitetura parece tirar proveito dessa definição de operação como 000 (que é o mesmo que não enviar nenhum valor nos três bits do "mini-barramento" de seleção de instrução) para efetuar, durante outras instruções não-lógicas, adições de entradas diversas A e B na unidade lógico-aritmética. Em outras palavras, se nenhuma outra operação for selecionada, por padrão irão ser somados os valores das entradas A e B enquanto são executadas outras instruções.

Por exemplo:

1. Dados três bytes consecutivos de memória, a saber: uma instrução não-ALU chamada DATA que move um byte na memória para um registrador de propósito geral, o byte a mover, e finalmente o byte da instrução seguinte, que em outros casos estaria na segunda posição (pois as instruções em geral ocupam um byte);
2. e dado também um *stepper* de seis passos (sete, mas o último faz retornar imediatamente ao primeiro);

...temos, de acordo com o livro, que:

Após os três primeiros passos do ciclo de instrução, que fazem o "fetch" da instrução DATA de opcode 0010, o quarto passo move o segundo byte para o registrador, e, embora não haja evidência na imagem abaixo, aproveita para somar a entrada A vinda do registro de endereçamento de instrução (IAR) com a entrada B antes da qual o "Bus 1" está habilitado (o que faz ela se tornar um byte fixo de valor 1), produzindo no registrador acumulador (ACC) o valor da posição seguinte à instrução armazenada em IAR, que cai no terceiro byte (visto que a IAR já veio do passo três acrescida de uma posição em relação à posição da instrução DATA).

[image: Passos 4, 5 e 6 da instrução DATA]

**A dúvida** que tenho é se este comportamento implícito de somar as entradas A e B mesmo durante a execução de outras instruções não-ALU é um design usual em arquitetura de computadores (digamos, para fins de otimização dos passos do ciclo de instrução).

Dela decorrem outras duas dúvidas que eu queria confirmar: primeiro, caso  seja este comportamento o padrão, então o que é feito da entrada B quando se deseja evitá-lo, isto é, quando se deseja não efetuar a soma e em vez disso guardar no registro acumulador (ACC) somente o valor da entrada A?

Imagino que para isso a entrada B precise conter o byte de valor 0 (para que ocorra efetivamente a soma A + 0 = A que é o mesmo que não ocorrer), porém seu valor sempre vem do barramento ou do registrador TMP que precede a entrada B (e que possui somente o bit "Set" e não o "Enable") e não vejo nenhuma forma possível de definir esse valor como zero, exceto setar o registro TMP como zero na instrução anterior à atual. Por acaso é isso que costuma ser feito?

Daí como última dúvida, não ficou claro de onde vem esse bit "Set" do TMP (acho que deve vir da seção de controle quando necessário, mas não vi no livro esse bit recebendo valor, por isso não tenho certeza sobre isso). Se bem que confirmando a dúvida anterior já fica implícito que esta última assunção está correta.

Enfim, na verdade é tudo uma dúvida só, que seria confirmar se essas minhas assunções mutuamente relacionadas estão corretas.

Comment: Para referência, a mesma pergunta na comunidade de Engenharia Elétrica da Stack Exchange: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/606563/304972